# Centering a list item

Tags: html, css, css-float, responsive-design, navbar

For a project, I have a (mobile) navbar with a menu button floating on the left and and 'back to top' button on the right. I want to have a logo centered in the navbar. I'm currently working with an unordered list.

The HTML basically looks like this:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <ul>
          <li class="navmenu"><i class="icon-menu"></i></li>
          <li class="mobilelogo"><a href="#top"><img class="moblogopic" src="media/navbarlogo.png" alt="logo"/></a></li>
          <li class="up-icon" title="Back to top"><a href="#top"><i class="icon-up"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.navbar{
 width:100%;
 height: 45px;
}
.navbar ul{
 padding: 0 10px;
}
.navmenu{
 display:inline;
 float: left;
}
.mobilelogo{
 display:inline;
 float:left;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.up-icon{
 display: inline;
 float:right;
}
```

margin: 0 auto; doesn't seem to work. I can't use something like margin-left: 50% because the site has to be responsive and resizing messes things up. The navbar currently looks like this:
[image: The mobile navbar with the logo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to set your widths then..:

```
.navbar{
 width:100%;
 height: 45px;
}
.navbar ul{
 padding: 0 10px;
}
.navmenu{
 display:inline;
 float: left;
 width:20%;
}
.mobilelogo{
 display:inline;
 float:left;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width:60%;
 text-align:center;
}
.up-icon{
 display: inline;
 float:right;
 width:20%;
}
```

Comment: This actually worked. I get the idea! But it's important to also set a min-width to the .up-icon, because if the screen-width is too small, It wil get pushed out of the screen. But many thanks!

Comment: The screen should not drop below `320px`. You can add to your icons: `max-width:100%` then if they don't have enough room they shrink - very useful with images in responsive design